# macOS catalina, Apache Benchmark (ab) not working, dyld library not loaded

Tags: homebrew, apache

I just got this error trying to install ab on my Catalina macOS:

```
brew install homebrew/apache/ab     
Error: homebrew/apache was deprecated. This tap is now empty and all its contents were either deleted or migrated.
```

not sure what to do...

Actually what I want to do is to make ab work:
I found out that ab (apache benchmark tool) is already installed on macOS, but it doesnt' work:

```
$ab
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ab
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: It seems to be installed in /usr/local/bin so it is something you installed yourself. Do you remember how?

Comment: @nohillside I read that ab is installed "by default" as is the apache web server...

Comment: `/usr/sbin/ab` is installed by default. `/usr/local/bin/ab` is most certainly not. Also, a built-in binary would not try to read libraries from `/opt/`!

Comment: @Wowfunhappy good point...my /usr/sbin/ab seems to work, but probably too late because I installed the library. Could have been that kind of problem then

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution on this post, https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/635

```
brew uninstall openssl; brew uninstall openssl; 
brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```